# ctrl+c "content" from css

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy-paste

trying to create a flexible mailing list with little JS:

```
.email_item::after {
     content: ", ";
}
```

resulting in:

```
foo@mail.com, foo2@mail.com
```

replicating with ctrl+c and ctrl+v returns:

```
foo@mail.comfoo2@mail.com
```

I'm going to have to use JS right? Or is there an optimizing genius out there?

Comment: pseudo-elements are not treated as normal content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, generated content like `:after` and `:before` is for display purposes only.
It does not alter the DOM so it is not selectable..

Why use JS and not directly add the comma at the HTML ?

Quoting [the specs about `content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content)

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).

Comment: because the list is flexible if one removes an element in the end and the comma is connected to the end of each element it will remain there..

Comment: @PedroEsperança, i see.. you will most likely have to add a `<span>,</span>` inside each element, and use css to hide the last one `.email_item:last-child span{display:none}` assuming your emails are all inside a common container.. If you can post some HTML of how you keep the emails we might come up with a better solution..

Comment: nice Idea :D that will work and is much less complicated from what I was about to do (rewrite the hole array every time a change was made :p) pfew, thanks :)